# Deleting an NSManagedObject in the Main Thread from an NSOperation

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsoperation, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When invoking `deleteObject:` on an NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread from an NSOperation, do I also need to reference the objectID on the main thread? Currently I am deleting an NSManagedObject in the main thread from an NSOperation in the following way...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
 {
     // Delete on main context on the main thread
     [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deleteObject:)
                              withObject:[mainContext objectWithID:objectID]
                           waitUntilDone:YES];
 }
```

It's working but I want to make sure it doesn't blow up on me later. The thing I'm not sure about is if `[mainContext objectWithID:objectID]` is referencing the NSManagedObjectContext from the NSOperation, or since that method invokation is within the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is it all being performed on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of NSManagedObjectID are safe to share across thread boundaries. However your call to mainContext objectWithID: will get the actual object, which is not thread safe.

What you should probably do is wrap this in a selector or block which can be performed on the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *obj = [mainContext objectWithID:objectID];
    if (obj) {
        [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
    }
})
```

Alternatively you can have your main thread queue do this for you:

```
[mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSManagedObject *obj = [mainContext objectWithID:objectID];
    if (obj) {
        [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
    }
}]
```

Of course, all of this begs the question, why are you trying to delete objects in a main-thread based context from an instance of NSOperation on another thread?

Comment: I am using your first approach (GCD). Thanks! To answer your question, I am updating a Core Data persistent store from a JSON file that I am downloading and parsing in an NSOperation. I check the JSON objects against the current persistent store NSManagedObjects. If the persistent store contains an object that isn't in the JSON I delete the NSManagedObject.